# How to fix RRTstar crashing on moveit?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am a beginner user of MoveIt. I have switched between every OMPL algorithm (switching among them in the context tab) but the RRTstar never runs and Moveit crashes. Any suggestions?

My Ubuntu version: 16.04
ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290910/how-to-fix-rrtstar-crashing-on-moveit!?/) by [enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/34982/enrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2018-05-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-11**:
Related/duplicate: #q230471.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My OMPL version turned out to be old, therefore I solved the problem by simply removing and reinstalling it (NOT from source!).

---

Originally posted by [enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/34982/enrico/) with karma: 117 on 2018-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
If this really solved your issue then it would be good to report that on the issues I mentioned in my answer.